# Como resgatar a localização GPS em coordenadas, de todos os usuários do aplicativo?

Tags: android, gps, geolocalização

## Explicação/Cenário:

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que deve resgatar em tempo real a localização dos usuários do mesmo, e estes usuários cientes disto, terão também, acesso a localização dos outros usuários, em um mapa, para encontrarem-se:

[image: exemplo mapa]

Essa localização deve ser em tempo real, pelo fato de que todos os usuários tem acesso ao mapa, e o utilizam para encontrar um ao outro.

## Pergunta:

Como fazer para que minha aplicação resgate em tempo real esta localização de todos os usuários, (em coordenadas) para que depois eu possa utilizar estas coordenadas e mostrar a localização no mapa de cada usuário?

## Observação:

**Não estou pedindo uma aplicação inteira, nem que façam uma para mim, apenas quero saber como resgatar a coordenada de cada usuário do aplicativo :) porém se quiserem responder mais completo incluindo a parte que mostra o usuário com tal coordenada no mapa, seria extremamente útil!**

Comment: Irei recompensar o usuário que responder esta pergunta de maneira completa, sendo que resolva totalmente o meu quesito, em 250 pontos de reputação.

Comment: Adicionei uma imagem exemplificativa que criei agora, ficou melhor? o que você quer mais que eu poste?

Comment: Na verdade ainda não cheguei na parte do Mapa, pois não sei nem como pegar as coordenadas ainda, (partindo do ponto da minha pergunta, porém estou lendo sua resposta agora)

Comment: Relacionado [Como obter a localização atual do dispositivo android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124634/2541)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Se o que você quer é um aplicativo pronto, [clique aqui](http://www.rdcworld-android.blogspot.in/2012/01/get-current-location-coordinates-city.html), senão, adapte o código abaixo.

### Pontapé inicial:

Há vários exemplos na web, mas parti de um [resposta do próprio SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/916193):

Antes de mais nada, isto tem que estar no manifest da aplicação:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Exemplo de uso da classe abaixo:

```java
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location){
        //Usar a localizacao aqui!
    }
};
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
```

Classe MyLocation:

```java
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //É usado o callback LocationResult para passar as coordenadas para o codigo do usuario.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //se o provedor de localizacao nao estiver habilitado, teremos uma excecao.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //Codigo para nao tentar fazer a leitura sem provedor de localizacao disponivel
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //se tiver os dois valores, usar o mais atualizado
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

> Nota: Na [thread original](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/916193) há vários pontos e modificações interessantes, recomendo a leitura.

Comment: Muito bom, garoto. Consegui resgatar as coordenadas certinho. Só que tem um probleminha... como faço para ficar resgatando automaticamente o tempo todo? tipo uma thread

Comment: @PauloRoberto essa rotina já faz isso, a função do exemplo deverá ser chamada toda vez que o usuário mudar de local. Para obter uma vez só você precisaria trocar os `requestLocationUpdates` por `requestSingleUpdate`.

Comment: Essa versão do SOzão é baseada na mesma solução, mas tem umas alterações interessantes, veja também se aproveita algo: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9811633

Comment: Ahh entendi @Bacco, muito interessante! melhor ainda do que eu achava :P vou dar uma olhada no link

Comment: Certo. Por acaso sabes como dar update em um "ponto" de um mapa utilizando api da google maps v2?

Comment: Pra Android só tem até o V2, um gringo me respondeu tudo que eu precisava saber no SOEN http://stackoverflow.com/a/23227090/2319589 detalhadamente :P mas valeu me ajudou como pontapé inicial sua resposta ^^

Comment: Cria um service pra ficar pegando as coordenadas em um intervalo.