# Como obter a localização atual do dispositivo android?

Tags: android, google-api, google-location-api

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação android que necessita obter a localização atual do aparelho (Latitude, Longitude) e usar esses dados no google maps...como posso fazer isso? Se me ajudarem a obter somente as coordenadas de latitude e longitude já será de grande ajuda...Obgrigado

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vou tentar resumir. Se quiser entender mais a fundo cada passo que eu citar, recomendo a leitura desse [documento](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/location/index.html).

**Primeiro passo - Configuração**

Adicionar a dependência no Gradle:

```
dependencies {
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.1.0'
}
```

Adicionar permissão no *AndroidManifest.xml*

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

e/ou

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

**Fazendo uso do GoogleApiClient**

Primeiramente, é preciso instanciar a classe GoogleApiClient, porque será através dela que iremos acessar os serviços que existem no Google Services, como o Location Service.

Criei uma *activity* pra demonstrar como isso acontece:

```
public class LocationActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this) //Be aware of state of the connection 
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this) //Be aware of failures
            .build();

    //Tentando conexão com o Google API. Se a tentativa for bem sucessidade, o método onConnected() será chamado, senão, o método onConnectionFailed() será chamado.
    googleApiClient.connect();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    pararConexaoComGoogleApi();
}

public void pararConexaoComGoogleApi() {
    //Verificando se está conectado para então cancelar a conexão!
    if (googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

/**
 * Depois que o método connect() for chamado, esse método será chamado de forma assíncrona caso a conexão seja bem sucedida.
 *
 * @param bundle
 */
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
    //Conexão com o serviços do Google Service API foi estabelecida!
}

/**
 * Esse método é chamado quando o client está temporariamente desconectado. Isso pode acontecer quando houve uma falha ou problema com o serviço que faça com que o client seja desligado.
 * Nesse estado, todas as requisições e listeners são cancelados.
 * Não se preocupe em tentar reestabelecer a conexão, pois isso acontecerá automaticamente.
 * As aplicações devem desabilitar recursos visuais que estejam relacionados com o uso dos serviços e habilitá-los novamente quando o método onConnected() for chamado, indicando reestabelecimento da conexão. 
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    // Aguardando o GoogleApiClient reestabelecer a conexão.
}

/**
 * Método chamado quando um erro de conexão acontece e não é possível acessar os serviços da Google Service.
 *
 * @param connectionResult
 */
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    //A conexão com o Google API falhou! 
    pararConexaoComGoogleApi();
   }
}
```

Se a conexão for estabelecida com sucesso, poderemos então usar serviços da *API*.

**Adicionando o Location Service API**

É simples passar a usar o *Location Service API* através do *client* que nós criamos. Basta adicionar a referencia dessa *API* durante a instanciação do *GoogleApiClient* assim:

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
```

Agora, poderemos usar a *API* de localização quando o *client* estabelecer a conexão. Faremos isso através da classe *LocationServices.FusedLocationApi*:

**Capturando a Última Localização Identificada**

Através da classe *LocationServices.FusedLocationApi* nós podemos capturar a última localização identificada dessa forma no nosso método `onConnected()` (pois é o método chamado quando a conexão estive estabelecida):

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        //Google API connection has been done successfully
        Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
    }
```

Quer a latitude e longitude? Basta chamar os métodos `Location.getLatitude()` e `Location.getLongitude()`.

Qualquer coisa comente!

Answer (score 4):

> Leia também [esta postagem](http://www.mobiltec.com.br/blog/index.php/tutorial-android-geolocalizacao/) sobre Geolocalização no Android

Antes de tudo, você deve adicionar no `manifest` do seu aplicativo:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Exemplo de uso da classe:

```
LocationResult locationResult = new LocationResult(){
    @Override
    public void gotLocation(Location location){
        //Usar a localizacao aqui!
    }
};
MyLocation myLocation = new MyLocation();
myLocation.getLocation(this, locationResult);
```

Classe MyLocation:

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MyLocation {
    Timer timer1;
    LocationManager lm;
    LocationResult locationResult;
    boolean gps_enabled=false;
    boolean network_enabled=false;

    public boolean getLocation(Context context, LocationResult result)
    {
        //É usado o callback LocationResult para passar as coordenadas para o codigo do usuario.
        locationResult=result;
        if(lm==null)
            lm = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        //se o provedor de localizacao nao estiver habilitado, teremos uma excecao.
        try{gps_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}
        try{network_enabled=lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);}catch(Exception ex){}

        //Codigo para nao tentar fazer a leitura sem provedor de localizacao disponivel
        if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled)
            return false;

        if(gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
        if(network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerNetwork);
        timer1=new Timer();
        timer1.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);
        return true;
    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer1.cancel();
            locationResult.gotLocation(location);
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
        }
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //se tiver os dois valores, usar o mais atualizado
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                     locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 else
                     locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(gps_loc);
                 return;
             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                 locationResult.gotLocation(net_loc);
                 return;
             }
             locationResult.gotLocation(null);
        }
    }

    public static abstract class LocationResult{
        public abstract void gotLocation(Location location);
    }
}
```

> Se esta resposta não satisfizer resultado esperado, leia [este](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-on-a/3145655#3145655)
>   tópico, do próprio SOen.

Answer (score 3):

Com a versão [11.0.0 do Google Play services SDK](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) a obtenção da localização do usuário tornou-se ainda mais simples. Agora não é mais necessário gerir manualmente a conexão com o serviço da Google Play através da GoogleApiClient.

### Última localização.

Para obter a última localização do dispositivo basta obter o FusedLocationProviderClient com `LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient()` e usar o método `getLastLocation()`.

```
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
protected Location mLastLocation;

@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private void getLastLocation() {
mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {

                //obtém a última localização conhecida
                mLastLocation = task.getResult();

            } else {

                //Não há localização conhecida ou houve uma excepção
                //A excepção pode ser obtida com task.getException()
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Não esquecer que é necessária a permissão `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` no *AndroidManifest.xml* e, eventualmente(`targetSdkVersion >= 23`), lidar com ela em tempo de execução.

### Monitorização da localização(Location updates)

Um pouco mais trabalhoso, principalmente devido à verificação das definições do dispositivo, no entanto mais simples graças às alterações introduzidas na versão 11.0.0.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS = 0;
    private TextView textView;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private SettingsClient mSettingsClient;
    private LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        mSettingsClient = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);

        //LocationResquest com as definições requeridas
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
        //Construção dum LocationSettingsRequest com as definições requeridas
        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();
        builder.addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest);
        mLocationSettingsRequest = builder.build();

        //Callback a ser chamado quando houver alterações na localização
        mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
                super.onLocationResult(locationResult);

                Location currentLocation = locationResult.getLastLocation();
                handleCurrentLocation(currentLocation);
            }
        };
    }

    //Inicia o processo de pedido de actualizações de localização
    private void startLocationUpdates() {
        // Verifica se as definições do dispositivo estão configuradas para satisfazer
        // as requeridas pelo LocationSettingsRequest.
        mSettingsClient.checkLocationSettings(mLocationSettingsRequest)
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
                    // Todas as definições do dispositivo estão configuradas para satisfazer as requeridas.
                    // Inicia o pedido de actualizações de localização
    
                    //noinspection MissingPermission
                    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest,
                            mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
                }
            })
            .addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    int statusCode = ((ApiException) e).getStatusCode();
                    switch (statusCode) {
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                            // As definições do dispositivo não satisfazem as requeridas.
                            //Mas podem ser alteradas pelo utilizador.
                            try {
                                // Mostra um dialog chamando startResolutionForResult(),
                                // o resultado deverá ser verificado em onActivityResult().
                                ResolvableApiException rae = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                                rae.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                                                             REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
                            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sie) {
                                Log.i("Location", "PendingIntent unable to execute request.");
                            }
                            break;
                        case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SETTINGS_CHANGE_UNAVAILABLE:
                            // As definições do dispositivo não satisfazem as requeridas,
                            // não havendo forma de as resolver.
                            String errorMessage = "As definições do dispositivo não " +
                                    "satisfazem as requeridas, altere-as nas Configurações";
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                 .show();
                    }
                }
            });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (checkPermissions()) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        } else if (!checkPermissions()) {
            //Não implementado, apenas necessário se targetSdkVersion >= 23
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
    }

    private boolean checkPermissions() {
        int permissionState = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        return permissionState == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }

    private void handleCurrentLocation(Location currentLocation) {
        textView.setText(currentLocation.toString());
    }    
}
```

Para simplificar não foi implementada o pedido de permissão em tempo de execução(só necessário se `targetSdkVersion >= 23`).
É necessária a permissão `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` no *AndroidManifest.xml*.

Referências:

- [Reduce friction with the new Location APIs.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/06/reduce-friction-with-new-location-apis.html)
- [Set Up Google Play Services.](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)
- [Solicitação de permissões em tempo de execução.](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)
- [Google Play services updated 11.0.0 - Release Notes.](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases)

Answer (score 2):

Recomento a leitura desse post http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/06/deep-dive-into-location.html tem uma boa explicação de como fazer isso, pois existem divesas coisas importante que você deve ter conhecimento antes de implementar.

Mas para um pequeno exemplo seguindo o que esta nesse link que passei:
Baixe o projeto de exemplo https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-protips-location/source/default/source

Copie a interface ILastLocationFinder e a classe LocationFinder para seu projeto

Depois implemente o seguinte na sua atividade:

```
locationFinder = new LocationFinder(this);

locationFinder.setChangedLocationListener(new LocationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {           
        //TODO o seu código aqui
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
});

Location location = locationFinder.getLastBestLocation(10000, 1000000);

if (location != null) {
    locationFinder.cancel();
    //TODO o seu código aqui
}
```