# getLastLocation as vezes retorna null

Tags: android

Eu uso o seguinte código para obter a localização do usuário:

```
@Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    m_api = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();

    ...

  }    

  @Override
  protected void onStart()
  {
    super.onStart();
    m_api.connect();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop()
  {
    m_api.disconnect();
    super.onStop();
  }

  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
  {
    Address address;
    Location cur = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(m_api);

    Geocoder geocoder;
    List<Address> addressList;

    geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(cur.getLatitude(),cur.getLongitude(), 1);

    if (addressList != null && !addressList.isEmpty()) {
      address = addressList.get(0);

      ...
    }
  }
```

De cinco dispositivos que testei, três funcionaram e dois não. Nos dois, que não funcionaram, o método "getLastLocation" retornou null e aborta a execução.

Eu coloquei no dependences do aplicativo 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.4.0'. Estou usando a API de compatibilidade minSdkVersion 16.

Dos dois dispositivos que abortaram a execução um tinha android 4.4 e outro 5.1.

Tem algum erro de codificação?

Será que o problema está na API instalada no dispositivo? Como testar?

Comment: Dispositivos físicos ou emuladores?

Comment: Dispositivos físicos.

Comment: Verifiquei a postagem, mas o problema é que _as_ _vezes_ o getLastLocation retorna nulo.

Comment: Isso é possível, você tem que lidar com essa situação quando ela ocorrer. Veja [isto](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html#updates)

Comment: Consegui resolver. Em alguns dispositivos o _getLastLocation_ retorna null. Por gentileza removam o duplicada para que eu possa postar a solução. E, se for possível, altere o texto "marcada como **duplicata**".

Comment: Se tem uma resposta deve colocá-la nesta [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124634/2541) que é a pergunta que inicia a cadeia de duplicatas.

Comment: A questão não trata o retorno _null_ do método em determinados dispositivos. De qualquer forma é possível "... lidar com essa situação quando ela ocorrer." (@ramaral). Encerro por aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Tente seguir esse [Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

Solução é substituir  no seu AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

por

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Eu tenho esses dois <uses-permission> no manifest. Mas, no link do tutorial quando chamado o método getLastLocation ele verifica se o resultado é != de null, resta saber em que situações o retorno pode ser null.