# Forçar o GPS do Android a atualizar a leitura

Tags: android, geolocalização

Recentemente adicionei a minha aplicação a funcionalidade de coletar
os pontos de latitute e longitude do GPS em que o dispositivo se encontra.

Para tal adicionei ao AndroidManifest.xml as linhas:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Criei uma Activity que implementa LocationListener

```
public class MinhaClasse extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {
```

e no Evento OnCreate instanciei as classes que serão utilizadas.

```
   locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
   String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);


   location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
   locationManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this );


   if (location != null) {
       onLocationChanged(location);
   } else {
       .... "Localização não disponível"
   }


@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        float lat = (float) (location.getLatitude());
        float lng = (float) (location.getLongitude());
    }
```

Desta maneira esta funcionando, acontece que o ponto devolvido nem sempre é o melhor. Na maioria das vezes esse ponto está a 50 metros
de distancia do dispositivo e eu não vejo como atualiza-lo. Quando essa aplicação rodava em um dispositivo com Windows Mobile eu lia 
uns 100 pontos e em seguida tirava uma média desses pontos e a posição resultante era precisa na casa dos centimetros.

Como posso 'força-lo' a atualizar a leitura quantas vezes eu quiser?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pode "forçar" uma leitura através de uma das variantes do método [requestSingleUpdate()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestSingleUpdate(java.lang.String,%20android.location.LocationListener,%20android.os.Looper)).

Com `requestLocationUpdates()` não é possível "forçar" updates, apenas definir em que condições um novo update é feito.

A frequência em que o método `onLocationChanged()` do *listener* é chamado é determinada pelos valores passados ao segundo e terceiro parâmetros de `requestLocationUpdates()`

```
void requestLocationUpdates (String provider, 
                long minTime, 
                float minDistance, 
                LocationListener listener)
```

- `minTime` indica o número de milissegundos **mínimo** entre chamadas.
- `minDistance` indica a distância em metros que o dispositivo tem de se deslocar para haver uma nova chamada ao método.

**Notas:**

- A precisão da localização não é determinada pelo número de vezes que a leitura é feita mas sim pela qualidade do GPS e condições de recepção(número de satélites).
- Se for passado o valor `0` a `minTime` o método é chamado quando é obtida uma leitura e não voltará a ser chamado enquanto não houver uma alteração da posição em `minDistance`.
- `minTime` tem precedência sobre `minDistance`. Quando `minDistance` for diferente de `0` haverá um update se houver uma alteração de posição superior a `minDistance` **e** se tiver passado pelo menos `minTime` milissegundos.

<sub>**Observação:**

Considere usar a Api [Fused Location Provider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) que a Google afirma ter várias vantagens sobre o LocationManager. Veja a documentação em [Making Your App Location-Aware](https://developer.android.com/training/location/index.html).

Esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213163/2541) tem um exemplo de uso.</sub>

Comment: Veja que eu passei 0,0 para que a atualização fosse máxima, mas isso não ocorre. Ocorre atualizações, mas não compreendi como. Já permaneci nos mesmo local e elas ocorreram e me desloquei e elas não ocorreram.

Comment: Sim, eu compreendo a questão da recepção e do número de satelites. Acontece que mesmo em condições favoráveis o ponto é impreciso. A técnica de ler várias vezes e tirar uma média surtia um bom efeito nos dispositivos Windows Mobile.

Comment: Veja que estranho. Alterei os parametros e coloquei um minTime igual a 100. Na volta do almoço, executo minha aplicação e a coordenada que ele me dá é a do restaurante, 200 metros de distancia de onde estou agora.

Comment: Vendo aquela chamada a `onLocationChanged(location);` no `onCreate()` é possível que essa seja a `LastKnownLocation`. O facto de colocar `minTime igual a 100` não quer dizer que o método seja chamado de 100 em 100 milissegundos. O GPS pode não ter conseguido obter uma nova localização entre o trajecto do restaurante até ao local onde está agora.

Comment: Agora sim. Usando a LocationServices API do GoogleApiClient as chamadas a atualizações podem ser feitas bem facilmente e as respostas são muito mais precisas. Apesar de eu estar em uma área coberta o ponto 'cai' exatamente onde estou. Valeu. Obrigado mesmo.