# GPS continua ligado após fechar a Activity

Tags: android, gps

Estou usando no meu aplicativo, GPS e Direction do Google. Está funcionando, porém eu notei o seguinte. Após eu retornar da activity onde tem o mapa, o ícone do GPS do smartphone não sai, ele fica como se tivesse ainda consumindo a atividade. Ele só sai quando eu realmente fecho todo o aplicativo.

A tela em si (do mapa), só traça a rota do usuário do ponto A até o B.

Alguma dica?

Answer (score 3):

Qualquer que seja o método que esta a utilizar para rastrear a localização do dispositivo deve iniciá-la no método `onResume()`/`onStart()` e terminá-la no método `onPause()`/`onStop()`.

Se estiver a usar o FusedLocationClient será qualquer coisa assim:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    } else if (!checkPermissions()) {
        //Não implementado, apenas necessário se targetSdkVersion >= 23
        requestPermissions();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
}
```

Ver esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213163/2541) à pergunta [Como obter a localização actual do dispositivo android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124634/2541) para um exemplo de implementação.

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. Segui o que você me passou e utilizei o método onPause() . Dentro dele usei o `LocationManager` junto com `LocationListener` que são os métodos que uso. Testei e funcionou.

Answer (score 2):

Para parar o serviço eu faço de uma forma diferente da sua. Faço com

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, context);
```

no onPause(), e no onStop() eu faço

```
mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
```

Comment: obrigado pela ajuda. Eu utilizei o método onPause() . Dentro dele usei o `LocationManager` junto com `LocationListener` que são os métodos que uso. Testei e funcionou.