# Que comando utilizo para atualizar de 2 em 2 segundos o meu código?

Tags: java, android, geolocalização, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou desenvolvendo um Aplicativo no Android Studio que pega a localização do dispositivo e me devolve em latitude e longitude, uso-a posteriormente para fazer um marcador. Entretanto, se eu instalo a aplicação no meu Smartphone em um bairro e vou para outro o Aplicativo não abre mais, fica dando erro na execução. Creio que ele só executa o código apenas uma vez, logo gostaria de saber um comando para o Aplicativo sempre atualizar o código em 2 em 2 segundos ou quem saber outra solução para o meu problema agradeceria a ajuda.

Comment: Tenta usar threads pra fazer essa atualização

Comment: Se implementar correctamente a [obtenção da localização actual do dispositivo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124634/2541) não precisa de se preocupar com o *"Aplicativo sempre atualizar o código"*.

Answer (score -2):

Você pode implementar ou abordar algo usando `threads` para atualizar seu objeto a cada X segundos:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

for(;;)
{
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        //Faz as atualizações que você precisa.
    }
}, 2000);   // Tempo em milisegundos 2000 = 2 segundos
}

}
```

Sugiro que coloque um limite no contador ou uma condição no `for(;;)` para os seus testes...

Comment: Além de ser uma má solução, o uso do `for(;;)` irá fazer que isso se repita indefinidamente.

Comment: Apontei uma solução, nunca disse que era a melhor... E como disse na resposta, o utilizador pode colocar um contador ou uma condição para parar o for(;;)

Comment: Devemos apontar soluções que funcionem sem trazer maiores problemas do que aquelas que visam resolver. :)

Comment: Bom, seu termo "soluções que funcionem" esta um pouco vago não acha ?... Minha solução funciona para o problema dele... Ele pode fazer adaptações ou customizações dependendo da necessidade. Apenas tentei ajudar de uma maneira simples e funcional..

Comment: Não concordo com "Minha solução funciona...", mas não vou discutir consigo, é uma "questão de opinião".