# Delay muito grande ao obter coordenadas GPS

Tags: android, gps, google-maps-android-api-2

Estou tendo problemas de delay na obtenção das coordenadas GPS. Eu pego elas no momento em que o usuário pressiona um textbox para validar os dados. Nos devices da Motorola vão bem. Agora testando no OnePlus 3T (A3000) e nos LG o delay tem entre 12 a 15 segundos,  não importa o provider ou o local onde esteja(garagem, subsolo, em um prédio, etc). E não importa quantas vezes o usuário responda o mesmo campo, o problema acontece.

Li esses links no SO:

[Getting too much delay from OnLocationChange listener.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31451714/getting-too-much-delay-from-onlocationchange-listener)

[Why Android LocationManager has long delay before location updates start if setting accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17249080/why-android-locationmanager-has-long-delay-before-location-updates-start-if-sett)

[Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)

Meu código:

```
public void getLocation(final LocationListener locationListener) {
        if (locationListener == null) return;
        LocationRequest locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        locationRequest.setInterval(500);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(500);

        LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(locationRequest)
                .setAlwaysShow(true);

        GoogleApiClient googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        googleApiClient.connect();
        PendingResult<LocationSettingsResult> result = LocationServices.SettingsApi
                .checkLocationSettings(googleApiClient, builder.build());

        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {

            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
                criteria.setSpeedRequired(true);
                criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
                criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
                criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
                switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                    case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                        LocationManager locationManager =
                                ((LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));

                        showError("NETWORK: "+ locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
                        showError("GPS: "+locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER));

                        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                        if (App.isVersionGreaterThanLollipop()){
                            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                                    ChecklistActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                                Location loc = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
                                currentLcoation = loc;
                                showError("BEST PROVIDER: "+provider+" CURRENT LOCATION: " +loc.getLatitude()+" "+loc.getLongitude());
                                locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(
                                        criteria, locationListener, null);
                            }
                            else {
                                requestLocationPermission(locationListener);
                            }
                            ...
                        }
    ...
```

Nem mesmo forçando NETWORK_PROVIDER eu obtenho uma localização rapidamente.

Para quem já enfrentou esse tipo de problema, qual a melhor abordagem para obter as coordenadas nesse cenário e de forma rápida?
Note que eu estou usando requestSingleUpdate. Isso influencia na obtenção dos fixes?

Comment: Você está a misturar dois serviços de localização: o LocationServices.API da Google e o LocationManager do Android. Veja esta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213163/2541), Nela, se pretender obter apenas uma localização, adicione `setNumUpdates(1)` ao `mLocationRequest` e ajuste os outros valores de acordo com as suas necessidades.

Comment: @ramaral Pelo que entendi do seu código, ele é apenas uma atualização (sem ofensas). Essa atualização melhora a performance do delay que havia comentado?

Comment: Você não está a usar a LocationServices.API da Google, para obter a localização, mas sim o LocationManager do Android. Naquela resposta encontra a forma mais actual/recomendada(há data) de obter a localização.

Comment: @ramaral Ok. Usando esta solução em Androids mais novos, o app voa. Porém, nos antigos Moto G1, G2 demora horrores para subir. Há uma razão para isso?

Comment: @ramaral Só mais um comentário. Excelente solução.

Comment: @ramaral creio que sua solução não é para ser usada. Chegou a ver esse link? https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: Essa parte da documentação está desactualizada. Ela ainda usa o  [fused location provider](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi) que foi descontinuado.

Comment: Você tem razão. Nem o pessoal do Google se entende.

Comment: Se quer manter-se actualizado siga regularmente o [Android Developers Blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/).

Comment: @ramaral uma pergunta, como você lida com os delays de obtenção de coordenadas e não prejudicar a experiência do usuário?

Comment: Se o hardware demora a obter a localização, seja qual for a razão, você não tem como resolver. Que saiba só há uma forma de minimizar isso: prover de imediato a ultima localização conhecida, obtida com `getLastLocation()` e de seguida usar `requestLocationUpdates()`.

Comment: @ramaral Exatamente o que pensei. Não tem como fazer de outra forma a não ser esperar o GPS "carregar"