# Como manter o MainActivity "alimentando" o map Activity?

Tags: java, android, gps, localização

Estou com esse código e no momento preciso passar uma latitude e uma longitude para receber no mapa e mostrar a posição atual em que o usuário se encontra, o problema é que ao passar para a `Intent` do mapa o `onLocationChanged` para de ser executado e não atualiza a posição, somente voltando para o `MainActivity` ele volta a ser executado atualizando as coordenadas.

Gostaria de saber como faço para deixar esse essa atividade atualizando constantemente a outra atividade, assim tendo um GPS em tempo real mostrado no mapa.

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;

import android.location.GpsSatellite;
import android.location.GpsStatus;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationProvider;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.Manifest;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements View.OnClickListener, LocationListener, GpsStatus.Listener {

    private LocationManager locManager; //Gerente de Localização
    private LocationProvider locProvider; //Provedor de Localização
    private static final int REQUEST_LOCATION = 2; //Utilizado nas requisições de localização
    Intent map;
    LatLng Local;

    //Inicializado aqui para não dar crash caso o mapa seja 
    //chamado antes desses atributos serem inicializados.
    double latitude = 0;
    double longitude = 0;

    //Pacote onde será armazenado o valor do LatLng.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Instância dos buttons:
        Button map = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_map);
        map.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button gnss = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_gnss);
        gnss.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button config = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_config);
        config.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button credits = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_credits);
        credits.setOnClickListener(this);
        //Fim Instância dos Buttons

        //O Gerente recebe uma location
        locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.button_map:
                Local = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                //Pacote inicializado com o LatLng
                args.putParcelable("Latlng", Local);

                //Criar tela relativa ao mapa
                map = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
                //O pacote é passado para a Intent referente ao mapa
                map.putExtra("bundle", args);
                startActivity(map);

                break;

            case R.id.button_gnss:
               /*Intent gnss = new Intent(this, GnssActivity.class);
                startActivity(gnss);
                */
                break;

            case R.id.button_config:
                Intent config = new Intent(this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(config);

                break;

            case R.id.button_credits:
                Intent credits = new Intent(this, CreditsActivity.class);
                startActivity(credits);
                break;
        }

    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // A permissão foi dada
            ativaGPS();
        }
        else {
            // Solicite a permissão
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    REQUEST_LOCATION);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        desativaGPS();
    }


    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, 
            String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_LOCATION) {
            if(grantResults.length == 1 && grantResults[0] ==
                    PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // O usuário acabou de dar a permissão
                ativaGPS();
            }
            else {
                // O usuário não deu a permissão solicitada
                Toast.makeText(this, "Sua localização não será mostrada",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        finish();
            }
        }
    }

    //Ativa o GPS
    public void ativaGPS() {
        try {
            locProvider = locManager.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            locManager.requestLocationUpdates(locProvider.getName(), 30000, 1, this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    //Desativa o GPS
    public void desativaGPS() {
        try {
            locManager.removeUpdates(this);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onGpsStatusChanged(int event) {
        // Alguma mudança no sistema GPS
        // A aplicação deverá chamar o método da classe LocationManager para 
        // obter   informações sobre o status do distema GPS.
        TextView coords=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_coords);
        String satInfo="PRN;Azimute;Elevação;SNR;Used in Fix\n";

        try {
            GpsStatus gpsStatus=locManager.getGpsStatus(null);
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    GpsStatus gpsStatus = locManager.getGpsStatus(null);
                    Iterable<GpsSatellite> sats=gpsStatus.getSatellites();
                     for (GpsSatellite sat:sats) {
                        // processe as informações de cada satélite
                     }
                }
        // Informações do sistema estão encapsuladas no objeto gpsStatus

        // Alguma mudança no sistema GPS

        // Informações do sistema estão encapsuladas no objeto gpsStatus


    }

    //Métodos criados automaticamente na implementação do Location Listener !
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        TextView coords=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_coords);

        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        longitude=location.getLongitude();

        //Cordenadas em DD
        coords.setText("Latitude"+latitude +"\n"+"Longitude:"+longitude);

        /*coords.setText("Latitude:"+Location.convert(latitude,Location.FORMAT_SECONDS)
                +"\n" +
                "Longitude:"+Location.convert(longitude,Location.FORMAT_SECONDS)); */



        //Passar o Bundle referente ao LatLng criado anteriormente.


    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
    // FIM dos Métodos criados automaticamente na implementação do Location Listener !

}
```

-----------------------------MAP ACTIVITY--------------------------------------

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");

        LatLng objLatLng = bundle.getParcelable("Latlng");
        latitude = objLatLng.latitude;
        longitude= objLatLng.longitude;


        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        float zoomLevel = 16.0f;
        mMap = googleMap;

        //Posição atual marcada no mapa referentes a marcação e setagem da 
        //posição atual na API do Google Maps
        LatLng posAtual = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(posAtual).title("Sua posição atual!"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(posAtual));

        //This goes up to 21
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(posAtual, zoomLevel));

    }

}
```

Comment: Relacionado(duplicata?)[Como obter a localização atual do dispositivo android?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124634/2541)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No seu `MainActivity` você está chamando o método `desativaGPS()` dentro do `onPause()`. Você poderia chamar ele dentro do `onDestroy()`.

**ATUALIZAÇÃO**

Para sua `MainActivity` atualizar constantemente sua `MapActivity` você tem duas formas de fazer isso:

1. Criar uma `BaseActivity` - uma activity genérica, no caso - que é responsável por realizar todas as funções referentes a localização que você implementou na `MainActivity`. Então, essa última e a `MapActivity` herdariam da `BaseActivity` e, portanto, seriam capazes de obterem as atualizações de localização.
2. Lançando um `broadcast` a cada atualização da localização na `MainActivity`, que seria interceptado pela `MapActivity`, obtendo os dados da localização através da `Intent`. Conforme eu deixei abaixo.

**MainActivity.java**

```
//Métodos criados automaticamente na implementação do Location Listener !
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    ...

    // Envia um broadcast a cada atualização com a localização
    Intent i = new Intent("LOCATION_UPDATED");
    i.putExtra("location", location);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(i);
}
```

**MapActivity.java**

```
private BroadcastReceiver locationUpdatedReceiver;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (locationUpdatedReceiver == null) {
        locationUpdatedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                // Obtém a localização passada pela intent
                Location location = intent.getExtras().getParcelable("location");
                // TODO: Realiza a atualização do mapa aqui
            }
        };
    }
    // Cria um filtro para o broadcast.
    // No caso, é definida que toda a Intent com a action "LOCATION_UPDATED",
    // vai chamar esse BroadcastReceiver
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("LOCATION_UPDATED");
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
            .registerReceiver(locationUpdatedReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // "Desregistra" o receiver para que não seja atualizada sua activity
    // desnecessariamente com o usuário fora dela. Mas você é quem decide        
    // se quer fazer isso no onStop(). Dá pra fazer no onDestroy() também.
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this)
            .unregisterReceiver(locationUpdatedReceiver);
}
```

Comment: é verdade, não tinha percebido isso, vou testar aqui, ty

Comment: infelizmente não funcionou, o gps continua ligado mas as informações não são passadas

Comment: Muito obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente, apesar de ainda ter alguns bugs que essa implementação causam, como uma demora excessiva de carregar o mapa, além de que quando eu saio da atividade relacionada ao mapa quando tento voltar para ela o mapa não carrega de nenhum jeito, porém ela continua sendo atualizada enquanto esta rodando

Comment: Qual das duas formas você utilizou?

Comment: usei o Broadcast