# NullPointerException ao obter a latitude e longitude

Tags: java, android, mobile, nullpointerexception, geolocalização

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação mobile com o Android Studio que tem como objetivo obter as informações de latitude e longitude e utilizar o serviço do Google Geocoder para retornar o endereço da posição geográfica. Porém, não estou conseguindo capturar a latitude e longitude do celular. Qual é o problema do meu código?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Location location;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private Address endereco;

double longitude = 0.0;
double latitude = 0.0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_denuncia );

    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        // Check Permissions Now
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,}, 1000);
        return;
    }else{
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.i( "Longitude", String.valueOf( location.getLongitude() ) );

    try {
        endereco = buscarEndereco(latitude, longitude);
        EditText editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.bairro);
        editText.setText(endereco.getLocality(), TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.i("GPS", e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public Address buscarEndereco(double latitude, double longitude)throws Exception{
    Geocoder geocoder;
    Address address = null;
    List<Address> addresses;
    geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
    if(addresses.size() > 0){
        address = addresses.get(0);
    }
    return address;
}
```

Saída:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos ver a [documentação do método `LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(String)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation(java.lang.String)):

> If the provider is currently disabled, null is returned.

Traduzindo:

> Se o provedor estiver desabilitado, null é retornado.

Vamos ver o seu código:

```
location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Ou seja, quando o GPS estiver desabilitado, `location` será `null` e você vai ter o `NullPointerException`.

Isso daqui deve corrigir o seu código:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_denuncia);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1000);
            return;
        }

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bairro);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (location == null) {
            editText.setText("GPS desativado.");
            return;
        }

        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        Log.i("Longitude", String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));

        try {
            Address endereco = buscarEndereco(latitude, longitude);
            String local = endereco == null ? null : endereco.getLocality();
            editText.setText(local == null ? "???" : local, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.i("GPS", e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private Address buscarEndereco(double latitude, double longitude) throws IOException {
        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
        return addresses.isEmpty() ? null : addresses.get(0);
    }
}
```

Outros detalhes a levar em conta:

- Declarar `throws Exception` é uma má prática de programação. Mantenha o conjunto de exceções lançadas o mais específico e o menos genérico possível.
- Evite utilizar atributos de instância para fazer aquilo que pode ser resolvido com variáveis locais.
- Um outro `NullPointerException` poderia ocorrer se o método `buscarEndereco(double, double)` também retornasse `null`.

Comment: estou suspeitando com algum tipo de permissão. Mesmo com o GPS ativo ele mostra a mensagem de GPS desativado. Dai eu abri o apk google maps e voltei pram minha aplicaçao, ai ele conseguiu retornar a geolocalização. Porem se eu desativar o gps, fechar o maps, ativar o gps novamente e entrar na minha aplicação informa gps desativado. O que poderia ser?

Comment: @CarlosDiego. Não sei, mas isso daí já seria algo para uma outra pergunta. O problema dessa daqui era o `NullPointerException`. Se/quando for criar uma outra pergunta sobre isso, recomendo colocar o código completo e compilável nela, além de descrever claramente os passos necessários para reproduzir o problema.

Comment: OK, vou analisar aqui, se por acaso nao conseguir abro uma nova pergunta. Mas funcionou parcialmente.

Comment: @CarlosDiego Ter o GPS habilitado não é suficiente para que o método `getLastKnownLocation()` retorne um valor. Para verificar que o problema é aquele que eu indico na minha resposta use a aplicação da Google e obtenha a sua localização, depois execute a sua.

Answer (score 2):

O método `getLastKnownLocation()` pode retornar null. Isso é mais provável se estiver a utilizar um emulador.

O método só não retorna `null` se alguma aplicação tiver requisitado alguma vez a localização do dispositivo. É claro que também tem de ter a "Localização" habilitada no dispositivo.

Pode evitar o erro testando se a localização é nula ou não, antes de utilizar o objecto *Location* retornado.

É claro que isto apenas resolve parte do problema. Para garantir qua a sua aplicação obtém uma localização válida tem de a requisitar.

Veja nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213163/2541) a forma mais actual(à data) de o fazer.