# Por que o marcador é colocado nas coordenadas erradas?

Tags: java, android, google, maps

Quero fazer um programa que ponha um marcador onde o celular esteja. No caso, eu coloquei a latitude e longitude de uma cidade na Groelândia, mas o valor da localização final é de (37.42342342342342,  -122.08395287867832), as coordenadas dos headquarters do Google. O que preciso colocar em meu programa?

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap = googleMap;
    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Service.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   String teste =  manager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
   Log.i("testando", ""+teste);
    provedor = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this); // Necessário para iniciar o provedor

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission") Task task =  provedor.getLastLocation();
    task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Location location) {
            if (location != null) {

                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                Log.i("teste", "pos "+ latitude + "  " + longitude);
                LatLng sydney = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
            } else { // Ao que tudo indica, a localização não é nula
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERRO!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A razão é estar a ser usado o método `getLastLocation()`.
O método retorna a última localização **conhecida**(pelo provider). Ela pode não corresponder à localização actual.

Para garantir que obtém uma localização actualizada deve usar um LocationRequest em conjunto com o FusedLocationClient, utilizando o método `mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates()`.
Veja nesta [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/213163/2541) um exemplo de como fazer.

Para verificar que é essa a razão execute uma qualquer aplicação, existente no dispositivo, que use a sua localização, como o Google Maps.
Essa aplicação irá requisitar ao provedor a localização actual, que passará a ser a última conhecida.

Volte a executar a sua aplicação que, uma vez que o provedor terá agora a localização actualizada, irá colocar o marcador no local esperado.